# Keyboard shortcuts to manage windows/workspace on KDE and RDP connection

Tags: windows, linux, kde, rdesktop, pc-bsd

On PC-BSD 8.1 (KDE) I have four workspaces.  I want to launch rdesktop 1.6 in one of them, full screen if possible (I'll settle for nearly-full in a window if I have to), and be able to do the following:

1. Switch between windows in the remote session using Alt+Tab.
2. Switch between local workspaces using either the default Ctrl+F1 or what I've switched it to, my preferred Alt+F1.

It seems if I use the -K option, I get 2 but not 1.  If I don't, I get 1 but not 2.  Is there no way to do this?  How can I tell rdesktop to send or not send a specific key combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [KRDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KRDC). You can switch on the fly at runtime between interpreting e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for the local or remote desktop. The switch can be triggered via a menu item, a toolbar icon or a (perhaps global) key shortcut.

Comment: Right, so you still have that extra step, same with rdesktop.  Is there a to tell KRDC to gobble only Alt+Tab?

Comment: Meh, I just disabled global Alt+Tab, it works for what I need at this point, even though it's not quite what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.